# Map Two arrays into a dictionary in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono

I tried this:

```
private List<GameObject> objects;
private List<int> points;
private Dictionary<GameObject, int> objectsAndPoints;

private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
    {
        objectsAndPoints.Add(objects[i], points[i]);
    }
}
```

But it popups an error like this:
*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

And there aren't things like List.zip or Enumerable.Range in Unity / MonoBehaviour, they are for .net

Does anybody know how to map two array into a dictionary in Unity / MonoBehaviour

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Enter the initial value. Otherwise there will be no reservation space for the dictionary.

```
private Dictionary<GameObject, int> objectsAndPoints = new Dictionary<GameObject, int>();
```

Also, if your list is set from within the code, make sure its initial value is not equal to null.

```
private List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();
```